# Direct image of a line bundle is a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Let
$$f:X\to Y$$
be a holomorphic map between compact connected Riemann surfaces and let
$$L\to X$$
be a holomorphic line bundle on $X$. I'm having some trouble understanding the fact that the direct image $f_*\mathcal{O}(L)$ of the sheaf of sections of $L$ is isomorphic to the sheaf of sections of a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ on $Y$ whose rank is the degree $m$ of $f$.

I understand that we need to show that $f_*\mathcal{O}(L)$ is locally free, and it is easy to see that this is the case around any regular value $y\in Y$. Indeed, in that case $f^{-1}(y)$ contains $m$ points and we can find a small neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^mU_i$ where $U_i\cong U$ so we have $(f_*\mathcal{O}(L))(U) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^m \mathcal{O}(L)(U_i)\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^m\mathcal{O}(U)$ for $U$ small enough.

But I don't understand what happens over a branch point. In the simplest case, let's say $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, $f(z)=z^2$, with $L$ trivial. Then, for any small disc $\mathbb{D}_r$ of radius $r$ around $0$ we have $f^{-1}(\mathbb{D}_r)=\mathbb{D}_{\sqrt{r}}$ so
$$(f_*\mathcal{O})(\mathbb{D}_r)=\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D}_{\sqrt{r}})$$
which is not isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D}_r)\oplus\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D}_r)$ as it should be. What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: Like the point is that the map $A=\mathbb{C}\langle t\rangle\to\mathbb{C}\langle t\rangle=B$ (where $\mathbb{C}\langle t\rangle$ is convergent power series in $\mathbb{C}$ at $0$) given by $t\mapsto t^2$ makes $B$ a free module of rank $2$ over $A$. Namely, $\mathbb{C}\langle t\rangle$ is a DVR with uniformizer $t$. A finitely generated module over a DVR is free if and only if it's torsion free. Evidently $B$ is torsion free over $A$. In your language, essentially $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D}_{\sqrt{r}})$ (which is notation I don't like) is free of rank $2$ over $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D}_r)$.

Comment: This should also roughly explain the general case by the 'local structure theory' of holomorphic maps between Riemann surfaces (i.e. that up to biholomorphisms they're the nth power map on the disk).

Comment: Did you have any further questions about this?